# Storing and getting json structure in database

Tags: php, jquery, json, angularjs

I'm using laravel and storing in a database a json string:

`[{label: 'Introduction',id: 'ABC'},{label: 'Chapter one',id: 'DEF'}]`

I would like to get this string using angular and use it in a jQuery tree plugin. I don't seem to be able to retrieve the string properly. It always comes out in the console as `undefined`. What am I missing?

**DB query:**

```
DB::table('documents')->where('id',Input::json('id'))->get(array('structure'));
```

**Angular controller:**

```
TopicService.load($scope.publication).success(function(data) {
    $('#topics').tree({
        data: data.structure
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the contents of data.  console.log(data)

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix an object like this `structure: "[{label: 'Introduction',id: 'ABC']},{label: 'Chapter one',id: 'DEF']}]"`

Comment: - is that what .tree() expects?  apparently it's not undefined, your question is a bit ambiguous

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix tree expects the json (http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/) - if I copy and paste, it works. when I console.log(data.structure) it returns undefined.

Comment: by the way "[ {} ]" is not an object its a string, if you use alert(data) does it say [object], or your json.

Comment: What does the database query give you? What does `Input::json('id')` give you? Is `$scope.publication` a correct path? What does `console.log(data.structure)` give you? It looks like you are just assuming that everything works flawlessly. You have to check for errors at every step and then either log it or shove it in your face somehow, or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok most likely, based on our conversation in the comments, you have a json string and not a json object.  You can either `parseJSON` the string or send the correct headers from php.

```
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 //echo json here.
```

Comment: alert(data) returns [object Object]

Comment: parseJSON got me half-way there. I need to store a **well formed** JSON string and then I can parse it right for the tree()